# Get only key from List of Map object using stream

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to get the Get only the key values from the List of Map object using the stream in java 8.

When I stream the List of map object I am getting `Stream<List<String>>` instead of `List<String>`.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class StreamTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Hello World");
    Map<String, String> a = new HashMap<String, String>();
    a.put("1", "Bharathi");
    a.put("2", "Test");
    a.put("3", "Hello");
    List<Map<String, String>> b = new ArrayList<>();
    b.add(a);
    System.out.println("Hello World" + b);

    /*
     * b.stream().map(c-> c.entrySet().stream().collect( Collectors.toMap(entry ->
     * entry.getKey(), entry -> entry.getValue())));
     */

    Stream<List<String>> map2 = b.stream()
            .map(c -> c.entrySet().stream().map(map -> map.getKey()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    //List<List<String>> collect = map2.map(v -> v).collect(Collectors.toList());

  }

}
```

How to get the key object from the List of Map object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use `flatMap` over the `keySet` of each `Map` within:

```
List<String> output = lst.stream()
            .flatMap(mp -> mp.keySet().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Aside: There is not much benefit that you get from modeling the objects as `List<Map<String, String>>` instead of a custom class and then further using a `List<CustomClass>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply `flatMap` it:

```
b.stream().flatMap(m -> m.keySet().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course `flatMap` is stream base solution! however you can do it with non-stream version in simple way.

```
List<String> map2 = new ArrayList<>();
b.forEach(map -> map2.addAll(map.keySet()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can use a slightly more declarative way:

```java
List<String> collect = b.stream()
                .map(Map::keySet) // map maps to key sets
                .flatMap(Collection::stream) // union all key sets to the one stream
                .collect(Collectors.toList()); // collect the stream to a new list
```